# Vue Components Styles not applying

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

This is my main container component,

```
<template>
  <div class="main-content">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my topbar component,

```
<template>
  <!-- top bar with back component -->
  <div class="top-bar">
    <div class="back"><i class="far fa-arrow-left"></i></div>

    <div class="page-name">
      <div class="main-topic">Management</div>

      <div class="dot"></div>

      <div class="sub-topic">Products</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End top bar with back component -->
</template>
```

This is my product component (With main container & top bar)

```
<template>
 <Main>
  <Topbar />
 </Main>
</template>

<script setup>
import Main from "../components/Main.vue";
import Topbar from "../components/Topbar.vue";
</script>
```

Here my CSS not working I have imported all my CSS files into the main HTML file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/negus.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="assets/scripts/jQuery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/jQuery-resize.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/script.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It should look like this,

[image]

But it look like this,

[image]

I don't know why my CSS is not working. Appreciate it if somebody can help. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code where you imported the CSS files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try importing those CSS files in your App.vue like this-

```
<style>
 @import "./assets/css/reset.css";
 @import "./assets/css/negus.css";
 @import "./assets/css/all.css";
 @import "./assets/css/style.css";
</style>
```

Comment: Not working sister I checked :(

Comment: Did you try exactly the same way?

Comment: Yes sister I exactly tried the same way

Comment: I tried reproducing your problem here, check this- 

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-swanson-2tkvf9?file=/src/App.vue

The css is being applied correctly.

Comment: I don't know sister why this is not working, Is it possible to check my code and help me shall I send my code to you. Searching for a solution whole day :(

Comment: Yes, send me the code, or try reproducing the problem at codesandbox or codepen.